# Android custom resource identifier in custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have began to develop a Custom Preference:

```
<com.package.lib.android.preference.CustomPreference
    xmlns:customPreference="http://schemas.android.com/apk/src/com.package.lib.android.preference.CustomPreference"
    android:key="test"
    android:title="test"
    customPreference:minValue="4" />
```

The associated class:

```
public class CustomPreference extends DialogPreference {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPreference(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        // how can I access customPreference:minValue?
    }
}
```

In my `CustomPreference` class I want to access `customPreference:minValue`. How is that possible?

Comment: Can't you just use the `AttributeSet` attrs? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html#getAttributeIntValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't used AttributeSets before so I can't tell you where the error is, but from my understanding it should be in there. set a breakpoint, debug and see what's in the `AttributeSet`.

Comment: Neither did I. I changed my value of `minValue` to `@integer/default_value` to hope to get it working. `attrs.getAttributeIntValue("vntnumberpickerpreference", "minValue", 0)` still gives me 0.

Comment: @Blacklight I found a way. See my answer below. It's quite some work to use the `attrs`, but eventually it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customPreference="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <com.package.lib.android.preference.CustomPreference
        android:defaultValue="@integer/font_size_default_value"
        android:key="test"
        android:title="title"
        customPreference:minValue="@integer/font_size_min_value"
        customPreference:maxValue="@integer/font_size_max_value" />
```

Create a `attrs.xml` file in `res/values` folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomPreference">
        <attr name="minValue" format="integer" />
        <attr name="maxValue" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

In the preference class you can get the attributes using:

```
final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomPreference);

Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomPreference_minValue, 0)));
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomPreference_maxValue, 100)));

a.recycle();
```